# spark + yarn cluster: how can i configure physical node to run only one executor\task each time?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I have an environment that combines 4 physical nodes with a small amount of RAM and each has 8 CPU cores. 
I noticed that spark decides automatically to split the RAM for each CPU. The result is that a memory error occurred.
I'm working with big data structures, and I want that each executor will have the entire RAM memory on the physical node (otherwise i'll get a memory error).
I tried to configure 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores 1' on 'yarn-site.xml' file or 'spark.driver.cores 1' on spark-defaults.conf without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spark.executor.cores 1`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11371611)

Comment: @Prune How does this not attempt to provide an answer? It might be completely wrong, [but that doesn't mean we should abuse the review queues to delete it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664)

Comment: The way that the audit questions have "trained" me on this is that a *suggestion* of something that *might* work should be a comment, not an answer.  If I've been misled by out-0of-date audit questions, I'll happily change.  Do you have a pointer to a meta discussion that would give me a better handle on the proper dividing line for the issue?